# Can I use JDBC blocking call in worker verticle of Vert.x?

Tags: jdbc, tcp, vert.x

I found the following sentence in the manual of Vert.x.

> Worker verticles are also not allowed to use TCP or HTTP clients or
>   servers.

JDBC is also a TCP client, right?

Then I can't use JDBC blocking call in worker verticle?

Reference:
http://vertx.io/manual.html#worker-verticles

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use blocking JDBC calls in verticles.  There is a [JDBC persistor module](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-mods/tree/gh-pages/mods/com.bloidonia.jdbc-persistor-v1.2) which uses the work-queue mod to share the load across multiple processors

Vert.x 2.0 will allow threading in modules so this should become less problematic

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Vert.x 3.x) you can deploy verticle as worker verticle or use

```
vertx.executeBlocking(...)
```

in both cases your code will run using a thread from the worker pool, and not on the event loop thread, allowing you to call blocking code.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTTP or TCP calls in a worker verticle but those calls must be "async". You must no block the thread. As Kamil (up) said you have to deploy the verticle as a worker and if you have a sync call, you should use vertx.executeBlocking(...).
Here you have some info: https://developer.mastercard.com/blog/the-vertx-worker-model